# how to remove last char from string

Tags: php, string

It might be a simple task. But I am new to PHP.

I am creating a string of values getting from database for a specific purpose.

How to remove last char from string.

```
$str='';
foreach($dataarray as $value)
{
   $str.=$value."##";
 }
```

it gives me string like `ABC##DEF##GHI##`

I have to remove last  2 chars `##`

**EDIT:**

have shown here sample code . actull y array is 2D. so cant use `implode()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `implode` method isn't appropriate, then after your `foreach` loop, you can try one of these functions:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

```
$str = rtrim($str,'#');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

```
$str = substr($str,-2);
```

If you have a 2D array, you could still use the `implode` func like this:

```
$a = array();
foreach( $foo as $bar )
  foreach( $bar as $part )
    $a[] = $part;
$str = implode('##',$a);
```

Answer (score 6):

You might be better of just to use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) instead of this loop?

```
implode ( "##" , $dataarray  );
```

Comment: Damn you were 2 sec faster :-)

Comment: I don't think its 2sec ... have seen 20sec delay and suddenly people posted the same answer has mine ... ( Not sure if it was even copy & paste )

Comment: Well, if you need to copy paste this that would be sorry indeed :). Anyway, @rizwan : I don't see much in multiple dimensions in your question. If your actual data-type is not a plain array, you should post your actual datatype. Just adding  `'##'` and then removing them again is probably still too funky :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use PHP's function [implode](http://php.net/implode)

`$str = implode("##", $dataarray);`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str = "1,2,3,4,5,";
echo chop($str,",");
?>
```

It will remove last comma (,) from the string $str

Answer (score 1):

Use substr:

```
$str = substr($str,0, -2);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Implode()` for making such string instead of making it manually

```
implode("##",$dataarray);
```

BTW for removing last char you can do like below:

```
substr($str,0,(strlen($str)-2));
```

Comment: Wouldn't substr($str, 0, -2) be better for your second option

Comment: better but i was not aware of it. Thanks for updating me

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to go about it but:

```
$str = rtrim($str, "#");
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php

```
$newstr = substr_replace($longstr ,"",-2);
```

This will create $newstr by taking $longstr and removing the last tow characters.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
$str='';
$first = true;
foreach($dataarray as $value) {
     if(!$first) {
          $str .= "##";
     }
     else {
          $first = false;
     }
     $str .= $value;
 }
```